# ruby method file or file_create method returns and does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my rails app and in my rails console I typed.

2.0.0p0 :045 > file 'file.txt', %q{contents = ['test']}
and it returns this.

Rake::FileTask foobar.txt => []

I also typed

file_create 'tesfile.txt' and it returns

Rake::FileCreationTask testfile.txt => []

I then type ls on terminal and don't know why the file text.txt or testfile.txt is not created.

I also created a file rubytest.rb with file 'file.txt', %q{contents = ['test']} and file_create 'tesfile.txt' then

typed rails r rubytest.rb and it returns nothing. I ls on terminal and do not see file.txt or testfile.txt

I running rails 3.2.12, and ruby 2.0.0p0

I've searched everywhere but still stumped.
Thanks for your help

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry i'm I very new. I just want to create a file.rb in my ruby app.

Comment: Have you read through the documentation for Ruby's [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html) class? It's the base class for `File` and explains methods like `new`, `open`, `read` and `write`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
File.open("file.txt", "w") do |fh|
  fh.puts "test"
end
```

I think you've inadvertently stumbled upon the rake [file](http://rake.rubyforge.org/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html) (scroll to "File Tasks") method, which is not what you want.

Also remember that `rake`, `rails`, and `ruby` are all different things.  :)  `rake` is a `make` clone written in ruby - generally within an app you wouldn't use methods provided by `rake`.

Comment: Yes that works and I'll read further about the link you provided. but dont understand why the rake file method or file_create method would not work in the rails console and with the ruby r command.

Comment: Rake isn't Ruby, it's a DSL that was written in Ruby. That it didn't work is probably good, because you'll learn to create files correctly, using Ruby directly. For now ignore Rake until you understand what it's for and what to do with it. And, though it might sound harsh, if you don't understand Ruby, you really shouldn't even be trying to write with Rails. Rails uses a lot of Ruby's deeper magic which won't make any sense to you until you have a good understanding of Ruby.

Comment: However, why would rails new -m file.rb able to run this rake method though?

Comment: My guess is that your Gemfile specifies rake, so bundler has loaded it.  Does it have a line for rake?

Comment: In Gemfile.lock. When i create a new rails app with rails new -m file.rb (with rake 'file method') it's able to run rake methods but I can never run this rake method in or out of the rails app once it's created. I realize it's not recommended to do this but I just want to understand what's going on here